# Detecting iPhone using Android Bluetooth without discovery activated

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, detection, proximity

I am trying to detect my iPhone on my Android 1.6 device using Bluetooth without interaction.
I can do it when the iPhone is discoverable, meaning I have to interact with the iPhone, going through menus to Bluetooth section.
For what I have searched so far, it's seem impossible to detect the iPhone, even if it has been previously paired (paired is only a kind of shortcut to avoid the heavy discovery process).
Does anyone know any solution ?

Thanks
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if the iPhone goes out of range or otherwise disconnects a BT connection, there is no automatic reconnect, you have to go in to the BT menu in the iPhone.
I have not worked on iPhone vs android on this, but I know a lot of the car stereo and gps manufacturers are having problems with the iPhone not reconnecting automatically.
At the moment they don't have a solution, so I doubt there is one.

Short edit for clarification: This is not an android problem, I work on BT certification and licensing, and android can drop a connection and reconnect automatically. (Under the condition that the phone supports that BP profile, but they all do.)